# Using the lock of synchronize block

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, synchronization

1. if I have variable `Integer[] arr = new Integer[5]` and i use one of the cells as synchronize block lock - can I use it inside the block?

   ```
   synchronize(arr[index])
   {
       arr[index]++;
   }
   ```
2. If the answer is yes - so what exactly the lock means? what the program do to this lock while synchronization?

another question - does it lock only the cell or all of the array?

3. In other words - Does another Thread can use the `arr[index+1]` in the block in parallel?

Thanks!

Comment: "does it lock only the cell or all of the array?" - Neither, nor. It "locks" exactly that code block.

Comment: Yeah I know.. I ment something else... I edit my question

Comment: Edit doesn't change a thing. No one stops you from doing anything with any arr[index], whatever index may be. All this code does is synchronize that one line of code based on the contents of arr[index] at the time the current thread reaches that statement. I'd expect unpredictable behavior from that code.

Comment: and why is unpredictable? another one - you say that in the block - there is no chance to change in parallel the same index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) .... can I use it inside the block?

Yes

> 2) If the answer is yes - so what exactly the lock means? what the program do to this lock while synchronization?

What it means is that some other thread that attempts to synchronize on the same object will be blocked until "this code" releases the lock on the object.

There are also memory coherency effects.  If you synchronize (properly) one thread is guaranteed to see changes made by another one.

> 3) another question - does it lock only the cell or all of the array?

Neither.  It locks on the object (the `Integer` instance) that the array cell refers to.

Also the lock applies *only* to other threads that attempt to synchronize on the same object.  If another thread attempts to synchronize on a different object, or if it attempts to access the object *without* synchronizing, then it is not blocked.

> 4) In other words - Can another thread use the arr[index+1] in the block in parallel?

It depends on *precisely* what the other thread does.  See above.

---

Aside: Your example is rather odd.  An `Integer` object is immutable, so there seems little point in synchronizing on it.  This may be just a contrived example, but if not, then you most likely have a problem in your application design.  Unfortunately, the example offers us no clues to understand what you are really trying to do here.

---

But the simple lessons are:

- you synchronize on objects, not array elements, or variables
- synchronization only works if all threads synchronize when using a shared object.

Comment: Best explanation! Thanks...  For protocol - This example only for me to understand better the engine...

Comment: Re, "An Integer object is immutable, so there seems little point in synchronizing on it."  It's quite normal to synchronize on an immutable object.  I've written more than a few `synchronized (lock)` block where I declared `lock` as `private final Object lock=new Object();`  An `Object` instance is immutable.  The lock object does not need to be a member of the data structure that it protects, and sometimes there are good reasons why you don't _want_ it to be a member.  The OP needs help understanding that.

Comment: Well yes ... but 1) it is conventional to use `Object` is you want a lock, and 2) this would be an array of locks.  I'm not convinced that the OP does need help with that aspect.  Certainly, the OP doesn't if this is merely a contrived example or if he should this was locking an array element in some sense.  We cannot tell.

Answer (score 0):

It locks the object (Integer) that happens to be at position index in the array at the beginning of the synchronized block. Which is not very useful in the case of Integers, because the statement arr[index]++ will replace the object with another (unlocked) one.

UPDATE

It doesn't lock anything useful, neither the full array, not the cell at position index. Besides, Integer objects (that are immutable) can be kept in a cache to be reused as a result of valueOf(). You may also get a NullPointerException if the array is not initialized.
In summary: don't do that.

Comment: So... you say that the answer is - 1. yes  3. yes?

Comment: @J.Doe The point is, you shouldn't be using that Integer as a lock.

Comment: why not? I'm really curios - and does it work or not?\

Comment: I *guess* you are trying to achieve exclusive access to a certain index in the array. But you are not. You have exclusive access to the content (an instance of Integer) which *can* be different for any thread but can also be the same. See Steven's answer. Pretty good explanation.

Comment: Re, "It doesn't lock anything useful", When you write `synchronized (foo)` it does not matter whether `foo` is "useful" or not.  What matters is what happens inside the synchronized block, what other synchronized blocks synchronize on the same `foo`, and what threads enter and leave those blocks.